# Using the geosphere distm function on a data.table to calculate distances

Tags: r, data.table, geosphere

I've created a data.table in that has 6 columns.  My data.table has a columns compairing two locations: Location 1 and Location 2.  I'm trying to use the distm function to calculate the distance between the locations on each row, creating a 7th column.  The distm package in the geosphere package requires two different vectors for each lat/long combo to be calculated against. My code below does not work, so I'm trying to figure out how to provide vectors to the function.

```
LOC_1_ID LOC1_LAT_CORD LOC1_LONG_CORD LOC_2_ID LOC2_LAT_CORD LOC2_LONG_CORD
 1       35.68440        -80.48090        70624    34.86752   -82.46632
 6       35.49770        -80.62870        70624    34.86752   -82.46632
10       35.66042        -80.50053        70624    34.86752   -82.46632
```

Assuming res holds the data.table the below code does not work.

```
 res[,DISTANCE := distm(c(LOC1_LAT_CORD, LOC1_LONG_CORD),c(LOC2_LAT_CORD, LOC2_LONG_CORD), fun=distHaversine)*0.000621371]
```

If I were to pull out each vector the function works fine.

```
loc1 <- res[LOC1_ID == 1,.(LOC1_LAT_CORD, LOC1_LONG_CORD)]
loc2 <- res[LOC2_ID==70624,.(LOC2_LAT_CORD, LOC2_LONG_CORD)]
distm(loc1, loc2, fun=distHaversine)
```

Really, my question is how to apply functions to select columns within a data.table when that function requires vectors as parameters.

Comment: There's no way your second example code that "works fine" works. You're missing a closing `)` in each case, and I think you should be using `list()` instead of `c()` anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to efficiently calculate distance between pair of coordinates using data.table :=](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36817423/how-to-efficiently-calculate-distance-between-pair-of-coordinates-using-data-tab)

Answer (score 11):

The `distm` fucntion generates a **Distance matrix of a set of points**. Are you sure this is the function you want if you're just comparing the points on each row, and adding one column?

It sounds like you actually want either `distHaversine` or `distGeo`

```
library(data.table)
library(geosphere)

dt <- read.table(text = "LOC_1_ID LOC1_LAT_CORD LOC1_LONG_CORD LOC_2_ID LOC2_LAT_CORD LOC2_LONG_CORD
1       35.68440        -80.48090        70624    34.86752   -82.46632
6       35.49770        -80.62870        70624    34.86752   -82.46632
10       35.66042        -80.50053        70624    34.86752   -82.46632", header = T)

setDT(dt)
dt[, distance_hav := distHaversine(matrix(c(LOC1_LONG_CORD, LOC1_LAT_CORD), ncol = 2),
                                   matrix(c(LOC2_LONG_CORD, LOC2_LAT_CORD), ncol = 2))]

#     LOC_1_ID LOC1_LAT_CORD LOC1_LONG_CORD LOC_2_ID LOC2_LAT_CORD LOC2_LONG_CORD distance_hav
# 1:        1      35.68440      -80.48090    70624      34.86752      -82.46632     202046.3
# 2:        6      35.49770      -80.62870    70624      34.86752      -82.46632     181310.0
# 3:       10      35.66042      -80.50053    70624      34.86752      -82.46632     199282.1
```

---

Update: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42014364/5977215) gives a more efficient version of `distHaversine` for use in `data.table`

Comment: +1! I can't seem to understand why the code with `matrix` works but this one: `dt[, distance_hav := distHaversine(c(LOC1_LONG_CORD, LOC1_LAT_CORD), c(LOC2_LONG_CORD, LOC2_LAT_CORD))]` doesn't. From the vignette, `distHaversine` can receive either a two vectors or two matrices...

Comment: I wrote a simplified version of `distHaversine` for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42014364/5977215) so it more naturally fits inside a data.table call.