# r extend data.table columns by filling row values

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table

I have a data.table:

```
library(data.table)
p1 = data.table(a = c(10.34,25.87,53.2), b=c(15.3,183.2,34.8))
print(p1)

       a     b
1: 10.34  15.3
2: 25.87 183.2
3: 53.20  34.8
```

What I would like to get is a new data.table with the following structure:

```
       a     b     a1    b1     a2    b2     a3    b3     
1: 10.34  15.3  10.34  15.3  25.87 183.2   53.2  34.8
2: 25.87 183.2  10.34  15.3  25.87 183.2   53.2  34.8
3: 53.20  34.8  10.34  15.3  25.87 183.2   53.2  34.8
```

My current solution is:

```
p2 = cbind(p,p[1,],p[2,],p[3,])
```

**How do I create a similar (other than using for loops) data.table p2 with 10001 columns when I have input data.table p with 10000 rows?**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: But why do you want to do that? It seems a bad idea, needlessly wasting memory for **10,000 duplicate columns merely containing the multiples `(n*a, n*b) for n in 1:5000`. Tell us what you are actually trying to solve**, what happens next to this datatable p1? (This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xy-problem))

Comment: ...but fundamentally, since we know you merely want replicated columns `n*a, n*b` with a multiplier n for n in 1:5000, we can just roll that implicit knowledge into your next calculation (tell us what it is), e.g. pass in that multiplier as a vector. I suspect you don't need 10,000 duplicate columns at all.

Comment: Hi, it is an input to a function. Maybe the faster way would be to create a dataframe with a predefined dimension and then assign values to them?

Comment: Then refactor your function to not require 1:5000 copies of the input columns, already. Which function is it? We really need to see that function code to understand why you think this duplication is necessary. Unless it's some external library/package/API.

Comment: It is an external function, distHaversine(). I'm using it as in the first answer on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213765/using-the-geosphere-distm-function-on-a-data-table-to-calculate-distances .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another option using `rbindlist` and `cbind` on `rep` for transposed data frame.

```
library(data.table)

cbind(p1, rbindlist(rep(list(data.table(t(unlist(p1)))), times = nrow(p1))))
#        a     b    a1    a2   a3   b1    b2   b3
# 1: 10.34  15.3 10.34 25.87 53.2 15.3 183.2 34.8
# 2: 25.87 183.2 10.34 25.87 53.2 15.3 183.2 34.8
# 3: 53.20  34.8 10.34 25.87 53.2 15.3 183.2 34.8
```

**Update**

@Frank pointed out in the comments that `cbind` can take unequal row numbers of two data frames. In this case, the data frame with less row numbers would be "recycled". So we don't need `rep` or `rbindlist` and below is the updated code.

```
cbind(p1, data.table(t(unlist(p1))))
#        a     b    a1    a2   a3   b1    b2   b3
# 1: 10.34  15.3 10.34 25.87 53.2 15.3 183.2 34.8
# 2: 25.87 183.2 10.34 25.87 53.2 15.3 183.2 34.8
# 3: 53.20  34.8 10.34 25.87 53.2 15.3 183.2 34.8
```

To get the col order as desired by OP, one option is `setcolorder`:

```
cbind(p1, setcolorder(data.table(t(unlist(p1))), order(row(p1))) )    
#        a     b    a1   b1    a2    b2   a3   b3
# 1: 10.34  15.3 10.34 15.3 25.87 183.2 53.2 34.8
# 2: 25.87 183.2 10.34 15.3 25.87 183.2 53.2 34.8
# 3: 53.20  34.8 10.34 15.3 25.87 183.2 53.2 34.8
```

Comment: @Frank Good to know. If we don't need to do `rep`, and then we don't need `rbindlist` as the purpose of this is to combine multiple data frames. So, this also works! `cbind(p1, data.table(t(unlist(p1))))`

Comment: @Frank If you don't mind, I am going to update our comments to my answer. It is good to know the behavior of `cbind`. Thanks!

Comment: @eod I've edited one way in. Not sure if there are others.

Comment: @Frank Good approach. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `shift`

```
out <- cbind(p1, p1[, shift(.SD, type = 'lead',
             n = c(0, seq_len(.N-1)))][rep(1, nrow(p1))])
setnames(out, make.unique(c(names(p1), rep(names(p1), each = nrow(p1)))))
```

---

or with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
pmap_dfc(p1, list) %>% 
             uncount(nrow(p1))
```

If we need the original data as well

```
pmap_dfc(p1, list) %>%
   rowr::cbind.fill(p1, .)
#     a     b     a    b    a1    b1   a2   b2
#1 10.34  15.3 10.34 15.3 25.87 183.2 53.2 34.8
#2 25.87 183.2 10.34 15.3 25.87 183.2 53.2 34.8
#3 53.20  34.8 10.34 15.3 25.87 183.2 53.2 34.8
```

Or with `transpose` and `bind_cols`

```
purrr::transpose(p1) %>% 
    bind_cols %>% 
    rowr::cbind.fill(p1, .)
```

Comment: for some reason, b.1 and b.3 have NA as a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option, similar to `www`'s:

```
> cbind(p1, matrix(rep(unlist(p1), nrow(p1)), nrow = nrow(p1), byrow=T))
       a     b    V1    V2   V3   V4    V5   V6
1: 10.34  15.3 10.34 25.87 53.2 15.3 183.2 34.8
2: 25.87 183.2 10.34 25.87 53.2 15.3 183.2 34.8
3: 53.20  34.8 10.34 25.87 53.2 15.3 183.2 34.8
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cbind(p1, do.call(cbind, split(p1, 1:nrow(p1))))

#        a     b   1.a  1.b   2.a   2.b  3.a  3.b
# 1: 10.34  15.3 10.34 15.3 25.87 183.2 53.2 34.8
# 2: 25.87 183.2 10.34 15.3 25.87 183.2 53.2 34.8
# 3: 53.20  34.8 10.34 15.3 25.87 183.2 53.2 34.8
```